# Some Stored Procedures won't get imported into ADO.NET Entity Model

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, import

I have no idea why ADO.NET Enity Model is skipping some of my SPs, althought I have put the `SET FMTONLY OFF;` line at the begining of every Sps

[image]

[image]

As you can see in the attached images, there is a discrepancy between the generated entities and the SPs I have on the server, only some of them got imported, why?

Any helps is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe for starters you should show an example of one that didn't get imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found it, the SP has to return an empty dataset even if the parameter is wrong or null, for example :

```
if isnull(@cityToGet, '') = '' 
begin
    select ResultDate, Prize, ResultString from #getResultByCity2
        order by resultDate desc, prize 
    return
end
```